# Parsing XML Embedded in VBScript (QTP)

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, documentation, qtp, procedures

Say there's a QTP Function Library that contains many procedures. Each procedure contains documentation written in an XML node format that describes the purpose, return values and other information about the procedure.

Is there a way to parse these XML documentation that is embedded in the source code just like how it is possible to generate documentation based on XML documentation in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's own XML parser should do the job. I've used it in a couple of projects. The SO posting [MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0 Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941725/msxml2-serverxmlhttp-4-0-source) shows how to find out which version is installed on your machine. Microsoft, naturally, has a lot of documentation. You could probably start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).